# Pie charts do not align with minipage

Tags: align, minipage, resize, pie

My goal is to display the two pie charts side by side at the same scale and to align them. It doesn't seem to be working for me and I'm not sure what the problem might be. Is it maybe the `\resizebox{}{}` command that causes problems?

Sorry for the messy code. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{7cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
                #2\printnumbertrue
                \else
                \printnumberfalse
                \fi}
            \newif\ifprintnumber
            \pie[
            /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
            radius=3,before number=\printonlylargeenough{3},
            after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi,
            text=legend,
            explode = {0.3,0,0,0},
            color={p1!50, p2!50, p3!50, p4!50}]
            {
                88.5/Fahrer,
                2.9/Fußgänger,
                7.5/Wetter,
                1.1/Technik
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \resizebox{7cm}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
                #2\printnumbertrue
                \else
                \printnumberfalse
                \fi}
            \newif\ifprintnumber
            \pie[
            /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
            radius=3 , before number=\printonlylargeenough{3.5},
            after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi,
            text=legend,
            color={p1!40, p2!40, p3!40, p4!40, p5!40, p6!40}]
            {
                20/Abbiegevorgänge,
                18/Vorfahrt,
                14.7/Abstand,
                10.9/Geschwindigkeit,
                3.2/Alkohol,
                33.2/Andere Gründe
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{minipage}\hfill
\caption{Ursache für Unfälle mit Personenschaden (a) sowie das Fehlverhalten des Fahrers (b) im Jahr 2020 nach \autocite{sta2021}}
\label{fig:abb1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please edit your question to provide something that compiles, starting with `\documentclass`.

Comment: The problem is that even though the pie charts are technically the same size, the overall tikzpicture has a different width to height ratio due to the length of the legend text. That causes a difference in size if you force both pictures to be the same width. My advice is to remove the `resizebox` and adjust the radius and font size manually.

Comment: Alternatively you can define a fixed height of the resizebox and let the width adjust itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `resize` I prefer to use `scale` to keep the text, line thickness, etc. unchanged for correct printing.

The only manual adjustment done is a vertical displacement of the first picture by -`5pt`.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 

%\usepackage{showframe}% margins

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{0.45\textwidth} %changed <<<<<<
            \vspace*{-5pt}% added <<<<<<<
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]%changed <<<<<<
                    \footnotesize% added <<<<<<<
                    \def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
                        #2\printnumbertrue
                        \else
                        \printnumberfalse
                        \fi}
                    \newif\ifprintnumber
                    \pie[
                    /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
                    radius=3,before number=\printonlylargeenough{3},
                    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi,
                    text=legend,
                    explode = {0.3,0,0,0},
                    color={red!50, green!50, blue!50, black!50}]
                    {
                        88.5/Fahrer,
                        2.9/Fußgänger,
                        7.5/Wetter,
                        1.1/Technik
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{0.5\textwidth}%changed <<<<<<
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]%changed <<<<<<
                    \footnotesize% added <<<<<<<
                    \def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
                        #2\printnumbertrue
                        \else
                        \printnumberfalse
                        \fi}
                    \newif\ifprintnumber
                    \pie[
                    /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
                    radius=3 , before number=\printonlylargeenough{3.5},
                    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi,
                    text=legend,
                    color={red!40, green!40, black!40, blue!40, yellow!40, violet!40}]
                    {
                        20/Abbiegevorgänge,
                        18/Vorfahrt,
                        14.7/Abstand,
                        10.9/Geschwindigkeit,
                        3.2/Alkohol,
                        33.2/Andere Gründe
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{minipage}
        \caption{Ursache für Unfälle mit Personenschaden (a) sowie das Fehlverhalten des Fahrers \\ (b) im Jahr 2020 nach}
        \label{fig:abb1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked perfectly fine for my code.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses the `[baseline={(0,0)}]` option to align the centers.  The extra braces are needed due to the comma in `(0,0)`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 

%\usepackage{showframe}% margins

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75, baseline={(0,0)}]%changed <<<<<<
                    \footnotesize% added <<<<<<<
                    \def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
                        #2\printnumbertrue
                        \else
                        \printnumberfalse
                        \fi}
                    \newif\ifprintnumber
                    \pie[
                    /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
                    radius=3,before number=\printonlylargeenough{3},
                    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi,
                    text=legend,
                    explode = {0.3,0,0,0},
                    color={red!50, green!50, blue!50, black!50}]
                    {
                        88.5/Fahrer,
                        2.9/Fußgänger,
                        7.5/Wetter,
                        1.1/Technik
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}\hfill
                \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75, baseline={(0,0)}]%changed <<<<<<
                    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
                    \footnotesize% added <<<<<<<
                    \def\printonlylargeenough#1#2{\unless\ifdim#2pt<#1pt\relax
                        #2\printnumbertrue
                        \else
                        \printnumberfalse
                        \fi}
                    \newif\ifprintnumber
                    \pie[
                    /tikz/every pin/.style={align=center},
                    radius=3 , before number=\printonlylargeenough{3.5},
                    after number=\ifprintnumber\%\fi,
                    text=legend,
                    color={red!40, green!40, black!40, blue!40, yellow!40, violet!40}]
                    {
                        20/Abbiegevorgänge,
                        18/Vorfahrt,
                        14.7/Abstand,
                        10.9/Geschwindigkeit,
                        3.2/Alkohol,
                        33.2/Andere Gründe
                    }
                \end{tikzpicture}
        \llap{\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}% show baseline, remove from final version
        \caption{Ursache für Unfälle mit Personenschaden (a) sowie das Fehlverhalten des Fahrers \\ (b) im Jahr 2020 nach}
        \label{fig:abb1}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]