# How to center image in table column

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable

I have created a long table over several pages. Here are the 2 first rows:

```
    \begin{longtable}{| p{.05\textwidth} | p{.10\textwidth} | p{.35\textwidth} |p{.5\textwidth} |} 
\hline
\textbf{Kt} & \textbf{Kap. 2.2} & \textbf{Kap. 2.3} & \textbf{Bemerkungen}\\ \hline 
AG & 0.80 & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{resultate/AG.png}} &\begin{itemize}
    \item bla1 lsdkjflksdjflksdjflk sdfdsf sdfs sfdsf sfdsdf 
    \item bla2
\end{itemize}\\ \hline

AI & 0.80 & \raisebox{-\totalheight}{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{resultate/AI.png}} &\begin{itemize}
    \item bla1 lsdkjflksdjflksdjflk sdfdsf sdfs sfdsf sfdsdf 
    \item bla2
\end{itemize}\\ \hline

\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
```

Here is the result of the code
[image: Result of Code]

How could I:

1. Vertically and horizontally center the text in the first 2 columns?
2. Center the pictures in the 3rd column?

Comment: use `\centering` to centre. note your table is too wide your `p` widths  do not allow for 8\tabcolsep column padding and 5\arrayrulewidth

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: \centering doesnt change the position. What is "8\tabcolsep" and "5\arrayrulewidth"?

Comment: \centering will center entries in a `p` column.  `| p{.10\textwidth} |` contributes `0.10\textwidth` plus `\tabcolsep` padding either side, plus the width of 2 rules `2\arrayrulewidth`  so your table will add up to more than textwidth(you must have a warning from latex)

Comment: Thanks @DavidCharliste. But how can I center the text vertically. When I put \centering{AG} in a p column, it only gets centered horizontally but not vertically and the picture does not get centered at all?

Comment: `\centering` does not take an argument, you are already adjusting vertical positio with `\raisebox` so you have full control of vertical alignment. as you have provided no example hard to help more

Comment: @ghxk Have a look at the `adjustbox` package to vertically centre images.

Comment: You also might put your images inside an \fbox to see how much white space is being added around the sides.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577687/align-tikz-pie-chart-caption-with-chart/577750?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C95.2567#577750 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614608/pie-charts-do-not-align-with-minipage/614706?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C45.6742#614706

Answer (score 1):

Just made this solution to center the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{vcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}|p{2cm}}

\hline

your text column 1& your text column 2&
\begin{minipage}{4cm}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=4cm]{image.jpg}
    \end{minipage} & your text column 4\\ 
    \hline
 & &

 \begin{minipage}{4cm}
   \centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{image.jpg}
  
    \end{minipage} & your text column 4\\  [\rowheight]
    \hline
 
 & & & \\
 & & & \\
 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please test your solutions before posting, there are several syntax errors in your code fragments.

Comment: thanks for noticing, I really didn't compile my code just posted the idea

Comment: is it nesessary to compile before posting due to the community rules?

Comment: It is good practice to not just post an idea, but to actually test it and then post a small but compilable document.

Comment: Please don't forget to fix the errors in your post

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've just made the new solution, it compiles without errors and I know that \vcell library should work for the centering in the table column height somehow